# How can I encourage the client's browser to use images from cache in node.js?

Tags: node.js, caching, amazon-s3

In my app, whenever a new image is uploaded to the server, it gets a unique name.
That means that if a client downloaded a file, it will remain unaltered as long as it exists on the server.

There is no need for the client to re-download the image if he currently has it in his cache folder.

How can I force/encourage the browser to keep the cached version rather than having him re-download the image every time?

I don't know if it's relevant, but when ever the client requests a file, it is streamed to him from Amazon S3:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
module.exports = function (router) {
    router.get('/*', function (req,res) {
        var path = req.url
        while(path.charAt(0) === '/')
            path = path.substr(1);
        var s3 = new AWS.S3();
        var params = {Bucket: 'mybucket', Key: path};
        s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(res)
    })
}
```

Comment: That sure is a lot of work for your server to act as a proxy.  Are you doing that because you don't want your S3 objects to be public?

Comment: Yes. that's my reason. Can you offer a better strategy? Also, is that the reason the client always re-downloads the file completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you pipe to res, set the appropriate caching headers :

```
res.setHeader("Cache-Control","max-age=" + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);//Cache for a year
res.removeHeader("Pragma");
res.removeHeader("Expires");
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you. Question: In case the file gets deleted from the server, will the cache still retain the image? is there a way to say "cache for a year, unless the file is no longer on the server"?

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do is set your max-age for a significantly lower time and then handle `ETag` requests.